# python call QPST to restore QCN failed "pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147467259), None)"

Tags: python, winapi, automation, python-3.9

During restore QCN using QPST tool, python returned below error information.
【in run_qpst_calibration
rcode = software_download.restore_nv(os.path.join(SCRIPT_PATH, cal_path), "000000", True)
File "C:\pkg_automation\lib\qpst.py", line 205, in restore_nv
self.software_download.RestoreNV(restore_path, spc, allow_esn_mismatch)  # restore the file
File "<COMObject >", line 2, in RestoreNV
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147467259), None)】
Before restore action, checked port status was OK and QCN file is existed.
sometimes the test code is passed and sometimes if failed and return above error code.
I checked the error code as following shows:

> > > import win32api
> > > win32api.FormatMessage(-2147352567)
> > > 'Exception occurred.\r\n'
> > > win32api.FormatMessage(-2147467259)
> > > 'Unspecified error\r\n'

tried many modules on different test computer, all happened this issue.
Please help analyze what's the possible root cause from python side. Thank you so much!